# How to get the earliest date for a number of groups- my query is only returning one date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with Dbeaver, and trying to write a query that returns the earliest date for a number of groups. Here is my code:

```
select MIN(date) as start_date 
from identity 
where data_file_group_id in (42, 43, 2134);
```

My issue is that the above returns ONE date, and I can see why. However, I am trying to get a separate date for each of the `data_file_group_id`'s. Hence 3 dates in total. Any ideas how I would do this?

The constraint is that I would like to run it in ONE query, and cannot use three queries to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should aggregate by the `data_file_group_id`:

```sql
SELECT data_file_group_id, MIN(date) AS start_date
FROM identity
WHERE data_file_group_id IN (42, 43, 2134)
GROUP BY data_file_group_id;
```